# Getting HTTP 401.2 Unauthorized when porting old Web Forms to OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization, owin

I've followed [Require Authentication for all requests to an OWIN application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524318/require-authentication-for-all-requests-to-an-owin-application/24619839#24619839) so my code looks like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() { CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never });
    app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        MetadataAddress = "https://login.windows.net/#####.onmicrosoft.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml",
        Wtrealm = "http://localhost:33210/",
        // SignInAsAuthenticationType = // This is picked up automatically from the default set above
    });


    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var user = context.Authentication.User;
        if (user == null || user.Identity == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Authentication.Challenge();
            return;
        }
        await next();
    });
}
```

The application is a mixture of Web Forms and MVC. I've removed all authentication types from IIS, removed the `authorization`, `membership`, `roleManager` and set `authentication mode="None"` in the `web.config`.

Now when I access site, either through the Default.aspx, an `[Authorize]` controller, or explicit AccountController that forces a challenge:

```
public void SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
            WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

All result in the HTTP Error 401.2 You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was

> I've removed all authentication types from IIS

At least `Anonymous Authentication` was required to be selected in IIS. The same error could be reproduced with the sample apps like [WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet) by disabling Windows and Anonymous Authentication in the Project Properties for IIS Express.