# How to get IOwinContext in AspNet Core 1.0.0

Tags: c#, authentication, owin, ws-federation

I'm using Owin and UseWsFederationAuthentication() in AspNetCore MVC 1.0.0. app. Authentication works perfectly but i cant SignOut the user.

This code

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignOut()
    {
        await this.HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Test");
    }
}
```

Throws:

> InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Cookies

The `HttpContext.Authentication` is set to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager`

Startup.cs:Configure

```
        app.UseOwinAppBuilder(builder =>
        {
            var authConfig = new WsFederationAuthenticationSettings
            {
                MetadataAddress = this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Eyc.Sdk:Authentication:WsFederation:MetadataAddress"),
                Realm = this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Eyc.Sdk:Authentication:WsFederation:Realm"),
                UseCookieSlidingExpiration = this.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Eyc.Sdk:Authentication:WsFederation:UseCookieSlidingExpiration"),
                CookieExpireTimeSpan = this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Eyc.Sdk:Authentication:WsFederation:CookieExpireTimeSpan")
            };
            builder.UseEycAuthentication(authConfig, app.ApplicationServices);
        });


public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseOwinAppBuilder(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<global::Owin.IAppBuilder> configuration)
    {
        return app.UseOwin(setup => setup(next =>
        {
            var builder = new AppBuilder();
            var lifetime = (IApplicationLifetime)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IApplicationLifetime));

            var properties = new AppProperties(builder.Properties);
            properties.AppName = app.ApplicationServices.GetApplicationUniqueIdentifier();
            properties.OnAppDisposing = lifetime.ApplicationStopping;
            properties.DefaultApp = next;

            configuration(builder);

            return builder.Build<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>>();
        }));
    }
}



public static class AppBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IAppBuilder UseEycAuthentication(
        this IAppBuilder app,
        WsFederationAuthenticationSettings authenticationSettings,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        bool authenticateEveryRequest = true)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }

        if (authenticationSettings == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(authenticationSettings));
        }

        if (serviceProvider == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
        }

        return app.ConfigureWsFederationAuthentication(serviceProvider, authenticationSettings, authenticateEveryRequest);
    }

    private static IAppBuilder ConfigureWsFederationAuthentication(
        this IAppBuilder app,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        WsFederationAuthenticationSettings authenticationSettings,
        bool authenticateEveryRequest = true)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
                new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    SlidingExpiration = authenticationSettings.UseCookieSlidingExpiration,
                    ExpireTimeSpan = authenticationSettings.GetCookieExpireTimeSpan()
                });

        var wsFederationAuthenticationOptions = GetWsFederationAuthenticationOptions(authenticationSettings);
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(wsFederationAuthenticationOptions);

        var eycAuthenticationManager = (IEycAuthenticationManager)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IEycAuthenticationManager));
        app.Use<EycAuthenticationOwinMiddleware>(eycAuthenticationManager);

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524318/require-authentication-for-all-requests-to-an-owin-application
        if (authenticateEveryRequest)
        {
            app.Use(async (owinContext, next) =>
            {
                var user = owinContext.Authentication.User;
                if (!(user?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false))
                {
                    owinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
                    return;
                }

                await next();
            });
        }

        return app;
    }

    private static WsFederationAuthenticationOptions GetWsFederationAuthenticationOptions(WsFederationAuthenticationSettings settings)
    {
        var wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications = GetWsFederationAuthenticationNotifications(settings);

        var wsFederationAuthenticationOptions = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Wtrealm = settings.Realm,
            MetadataAddress = settings.MetadataAddress,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudiences = settings.Realms
            },
            Notifications = wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
        };

        if (settings.UseCookieSlidingExpiration)
        {
            // this needs to be false for sliding expiration to work
            wsFederationAuthenticationOptions.UseTokenLifetime = false;
        }

        return wsFederationAuthenticationOptions;
    }

    private static WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications GetWsFederationAuthenticationNotifications(WsFederationAuthenticationSettings settings)
    {
        var wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications();
        wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.AuthenticationFailed = settings.AuthenticationFailed ?? wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.AuthenticationFailed;
        wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.MessageReceived = settings.MessageReceived ?? wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.MessageReceived;
        wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.RedirectToIdentityProvider = settings.RedirectToIdentityProvider ?? wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.RedirectToIdentityProvider;
        wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.SecurityTokenReceived = settings.SecurityTokenReceived ?? wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.SecurityTokenReceived;
        wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.SecurityTokenValidated = settings.SecurityTokenValidated ?? wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.SecurityTokenValidated;

        return wsFederationAuthenticationNotifications;
    }
}


public class EycAuthenticationOwinMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private readonly IEycAuthenticationManager _eycAuthenticationManager;

    #region ctors

    public EycAuthenticationOwinMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, IEycAuthenticationManager eycAuthenticationManager)
        : base(next)
    {
        if (eycAuthenticationManager == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eycAuthenticationManager));
        }

        this._eycAuthenticationManager = eycAuthenticationManager;
    }

    #endregion

    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (context.Authentication.User != null)
        {
            context.Authentication.User =
                this._eycAuthenticationManager.Authenticate(
                    context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri,
                    context.Authentication.User);
        }

        return this.Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}


public class EycAuthenticationManager : ClaimsAuthenticationManager, IEycAuthenticationManager
{
    private readonly IClaimsTransformer _claimsTransformer;

    #region ctors

    public EycAuthenticationManager(IClaimsTransformer claimsTransformer)
    {
        this._claimsTransformer = claimsTransformer;
    }

    #endregion

    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        if (incomingPrincipal != null && !incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
        }

        return this._claimsTransformer.TransformIdentity(incomingPrincipal);
    }
}


public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformer
{
    public ClaimsPrincipal TransformIdentity(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (!(principal is ClaimsPrincipal))
        {
            throw new Exception("The provided IPrincipal object is not of type ClaimsPrincipal.");
        }

        var user = (ClaimsPrincipal)principal;

        var claims = user.Claims.ToList();

        if (claims.All(x => x.Type != ClaimTypes.Email))
        {
            var upnClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Upn);
            if (upnClaim != null)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, upnClaim.Value));
            }
        }

        return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, principal.Identity.AuthenticationType));
    }
}
```

Comment: How you configure in your Startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way how to SignOut using Owin context, app is "IAppBuilder":

```
        app.Map("/signout", map =>
        {
            map.Run(ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Authentication.SignOut();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        });
```

More details here: https://leastprivilege.com/2014/02/21/test-driving-the-ws-federation-authentication-middleware-for-katana/

Comment: Wow thanks it took me ages to find your answer. It is unbelievably painful to try and use WS Federation with ASP.Net Core, even targeting the full .Net Framework. Someone should write a concise example!

Comment: @user917170 Yeay, you tell me that ;). It took ages to me.

Answer (score 0):

UseWsFederationAuthentication will not work in AspNetCore MVC 1.0.0. UseWsFederationAuthentication used non-standard OWIN keys that are not supported by UseOwin, so it cannot communicate with MVC.

Comment: Is there any replacement for that or a workaround? Actually the Authentication works, but I can't figure out how to SignOut.

Comment: Not yet, we're waiting for some dependencies to be ported over. Some people are using OpenIdConnect instead.

Comment: OpenIdConnect can replace the Ws-Federated auth?

Comment: For some scenarios, like Azure AD, but not for local scenarios.

Comment: Hmm, seems I have to wait or figure out how to signout user differently. Deleting auth. cookie should be enough, probably.